# get last one hour records in elasticsearch

Tags: sql, node.js, elasticsearch, kibana

I have following mapping on my date column:

```
"order_datetime": {
    "type": "date",
    "format" : "yyyy-M-d H:m:s"
}
```

I am trying to get last one hour records using following range filter in query:

```
{
    "range": {
        "order_datetime": {
            "gte": "now-1h",
            "lte": "now"
        }
    }
}
```

I am getting orders that are ordered before 5 to 6 hours from current time. Can anyone explain why its happening? I think it's a timezone problem so attached the `time_zone` as below:

```
{
    "range": {
        "order_datetime": {
            "gte": "now-1h",
            "lte": "now",
            "time_zone": "+05:30"
        }
    }
}
```

Still I am getting the same result. Please help

Comment: What is the time-zone of the server where ES is installed?

Comment: it's Asia/Kolkata i.e. +05:30 from utc

Comment: If using kibana, then you can go to Advanced Setting and change time-zone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, it'd be useful to know if you are using Kibana to visualise your data?

The behaviour is a little odd, but can be explained.

Elastic assumes you are storing dates in UTC (unless you tell it otherwise). Suppose now is 16:30 in your time zone and you index a document with 16:30 in the date field. Elastic thinks this is 16:30 UTC, whereas it's actually only 11:00 in UTC (assuming you are 5:30 ahead) - the date 'now' in Elastic is always UTC.

So, you have two options -

1. Index your data so that you pass the time-zone with the date
2. Change your query to `"lte": "now+5h+30m"`

When specifying the `time_zone` in the range query it does nothing to `now` as per the documentation.

See 'Time zone in range query' - https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-range-query.html